# I created my own Linux shell but get "mctrl: Permission denied" on login?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, permissions

I have a tiny shell in C which does nothing but print "Hello, im a shell\n".
Everytime I try to `login johndoe` the default way i get Login failed, and using `sudo su johndoe` gives me exactly `mctrl: Permission denied`.

*Am i missing something simple? What does bash have which i dont =( ?*

**Update1:** I forgot to specify the absolute path naming the shell. however the error still occours.

**Updatate2[solved]:** No links are allowed for shells, and should be in /bin/ or some other directory with respect!

PS: The shell will be given users to control their minecraft servres in a simple way through ssh, or give adminstration password to get into bash.

Comment: Does the user `johndoe` have execute permissions on the shell? And is it located somewhere he can get to?

Comment: @SpencerRathbun It was not located where everyone had access to, it was my home directory which i set my umask to 077. Now ive moved the original file to /bin/ and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I would check would be file and directory permissions. Does `johndoe` have access to the shell executable (and all its parent directories), and is the "execute" permission set correctly?

If you change `johndoe`'s shell to `bash`, are you able to log in as `johndoe` and manually execute your custom shell?

Comment: I am. `sudo su johndoe` works now. HOWEVER logging in as johndoe with the correct password still gives me *Login incorrect*. Why does switch-user work and this not ?! Do i need the suid bit to be set ?